# Best way to populate array object with another dataset

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm trying to populate my `list` with some data return from the function `function` but this approach didn't work.

`function.findSomeData` request data from oracle database and my `index` is reaching list.lenght before callback from `function.findSomeData`

```js
for (index; index < originalList.length; index++) {
  this.function.findSomeData(
    param1,
    null,
    null,
    param2,
    conn,
    true,
    lang,
    (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        super.doReleaseNewConn(connection, conn, !autoCommit);
        callback(err, null);
      } else {
        if (!Validator.isNullUndefinedEmpty(result)) {
          list.push(result[0]);
        }
        if (index >= originalList.length) {
          callback(null, list);
        }
      }
    }
  );
}
```

Which is the best and correct way to do this?

-- **Solved** by updating `findSomeData`:

Now, i'm calling `findSomeData`passing an index and both lists (originalList, finalList). Inside de function, i'm interating the db request controlling the `index` by originalList.lenght and pushing the returned data into finalList, as:

```
this.function.findSomeData(
    0,
    originalList,
    list,
    param2,
    conn,
    true,
    lang,
    (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        super.doReleaseNewConn(connection, conn, !autoCommit);
        callback(err, null);
      } else {
        if (!Validator.isNullUndefinedEmpty(result)) {
          list.push(result[0]);
        }
        if (index >= originalList.length) {
          callback(null, list);
        }
      }
    }
  );
```

And

```
public findSomeData(
    index: number,
    originalList: [],
    list: [],
    connection: Connection,
    autoCommit: boolean,
    lang: string,
    callback: (errorBuscaListaCliente: string, list: []) => void
  ) {
    try {
      if (indice < listaUc.length) {
       --db requests and another things
      } else {
       callback(null, list);
      }
```

Comment: also explain what you mean by " _.. it didn't work_". are you getting an error? The result isn't what you desired?

Comment: list is defined before the for, like let list: [] = new Array<>(); (Of specifc data; list and result are the same type). My problem is probably related to function.findSomeData request data from db returning after index reach list.length

Comment: I'm getting no error! Only an empy list. If i run findSomeData directly in db or with 1 item from list i can read the callback from findSomeData